# How to pass value/parameter into a "public delegate void"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Please help me with this. Let's say I have this code here...

```
    void IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected(MWResult result)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var scan = Element as BarcodeScannerModal;

                if (scan == null)
                    return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

...and I want that value of MWResult result be passed to this one...

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
        public delegate void EventScanHandler(MWResult result);
```

I'm really having trouble with this one.

Comment: `EventScanHandler` is a (delegate) Type. You will need to get a reference from somewhere. No clues in your question. `EventScanHandler myHandler = ...;`

Answer (score 1):

How a basic delegate void is used. A delegate void is a method on where an object  or a void is referenced. Its almost like a place holder if you have two of the same function and you need to switch the function, not so much the numbers (swith the + in **5+5** into a *, like **5*5**, the example below shows how to do this. **It doesent also have to be an int as a return! You can also swith it out for a void in order to do functions**). In your case you want to scan the bar-code then check if it is `null` so I'm confused on why you would want to use a delegate void.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    //delegates are mostly defined outside of the class
    public delegate int addn(int num1, int num2);

    //the main class

    class Program
    {
        //delegate functions
        public static int add1(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 + num2;
        }

        public static int add2(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return num1 * num2;
        }

        //entry
        public static void Main()
        {
            //here we can reference delegates as a class. its
            //called addf in this case.

            //first we init add1
            addn addf = new addn(add1);
            Console.WriteLine(addf(5, 5));

            //then we innit add2. note we dont add /*addn*/ in the beginning because
            //its already defined
            addf = new addn(add2);
            Console.WriteLine(addf(5, 5));

            //loop

            while (true) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you are using different versions of *IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected* I would just call it directly, store the value in a class, then use `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
        public delegate void EventScanHandler(`Class name `result);`

Comment: Thanks. Turns out to be pretty helpful, however, I'm getting a value "null" though. I guess I'm near from making it correct 'cause the errors are gone...

Comment: @JHONCARLIGNORO That means, through your code, that there is an error. I would recomend going step by step and logging with `Console.WriteLine` in order to find out where and why its null

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is a type that represents references to methods.

```
ScanSuccessCallbackImpl t = new ScanSuccessCallbackImpl();
EventScanHandler method = t.barcodeDetected;
method(new MWResult());
```

Does this answers your question?